# Toolbar button unresponsive after iOS 13.4.1 update

Tags: objective-c, toolbar, ios13, uitoolbar

I have had a medical calculation app for cardiac ultrasound in the App Store since 2011. At the bottom of each data entry screen is a toolbar with buttons to analyze all data, designate the open calculation as a favorite, and clear all active data from all calculations.  After the most recent iOS update to 13.4.1, the Clear button at the bottom right of the screen has become unresponsive.  If I put the  app in the background, open another app, and then switch back to my app, then the Clear button becomes responsive again.  If I move the Clear button to the left side of the toolbar, next to the Analyze button, then it functions without a problem.  Since the code that displays these buttons has been the same for years and multiple iOS versions, I am wondering if possibly there is a bug in iOS 13.4.1 causing this issue.

Here is the code used to generate the toolbar:

```
//Initialize the toolbar
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

//Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app.
[toolbar sizeToFit];

//Caclulate the height of the toolbar
CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

//Get the bounds of the parent view
CGRect rootViewBounds = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;

//Get the height of the parent view.
CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);

//Get the width of the parent view,
CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

//Create a rectangle for the toolbar
CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight - [sharedVariableState g_toolbar_adjuster_for_Home_indicator], rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);

//Reposition and resize the receiver
[toolbar setFrame:rectArea];

//Create two buttons separated by spacer item.
UIBarButtonItem *analyzeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Analyze" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(analyze_clicked:)];

UIBarButtonItem *clearButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(clear_clicked:)];

//Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  //Load NSUserDefaults.
NSMutableArray *objectArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

objectArrayMutable = [[prefs objectForKey:@"savedFavoritesArray"] mutableCopy];

int favoriteChosenAlready = 0;

if ([objectArrayMutable count] > 0) {
    for (int arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < [objectArrayMutable count]; arrayCounter++) {
        if ([[objectArrayMutable objectAtIndex:arrayCounter] integerValue] == 58) {
            favoriteChosenAlready = 1;
        }
    }
}

UIButton *favButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
if (favoriteChosenAlready == 0) {
    //Display empty star.
    [favButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Star_button_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    //Display filled star.
    [favButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Star_button_filled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

[favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(favorite_clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[favButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 25, 30, 30)];
UIBarButtonItem *favoriteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:favButton];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]; //Make toolbar button text lightGrayColor.

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:analyzeButton,flexItem,favoriteButton,flexItem,clearButton,nil]];

//Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

To clarify, the Clear button here now is unresponsive:
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:analyzeButton,flexItem,favoriteButton,flexItem,clearButton,nil]];

However, just rearranging the sequence of buttons in the toolbar fixes the problem:
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:analyzeButton,clearButton,favoriteButton,flexItem,flexItem,nil]];

Comment: I'm running into exactly the same issue. I have an "add" button on the toolbar, and it doesn't work on some iOS13 devices. I have only one toolbar button, so rearranging it doesn't help either. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I did finally fix the problem.  Seems that the iOS 13 update changed how objects layer when displayed, so my Clear button essentially was being "covered" by the Favorite button in the middle of the toolbar.  I fixed the problem in my code by replacing [favButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 25, 30, 30)]; with [favButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];  Hope this info helps.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, there was only 1 UIBarButtonItem in the toolbar, so this fix wouldn't work. I ended up replacing the toolbar with a custom UIView and regular buttons.